# Settings for real-time QCustomPlot

Tags: c++, qt, plot, real-time-data, qcustomplot

I use Windows 7 x64, Qt 5.6, Visual Studio 2015, QCustomPlot 1.3.2. I need to draw temperature graph from a sensor (real time). I receive temperature value every 500 ms (`frequency` = 2 Hz). What settings should I apply to `QCustomPlot` instance in order to have the last values received during `time_period` = 10 minutes?
Here is a fragment of renewal slot:

```
double key = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toMSecsSinceEpoch() / 1000.0;
custom_plot_->graph(0)->addData(key, value);
custom_plot_->graph(0)->removeDataBefore(old_items_count);
custom_plot_->xAxis->setRange(key + some_delta, old_items_count, Qt::AlignRight);
```

What are the formulas for variables `old_items_count = func1(time_period, frequency)` and `some_delta = func2(time_period, frequency)`?
Official demo contains the following values: `old_items_count = 8`, `some_delta = 0.25`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `xAxis` is in seconds, in order to have a constant range of 10 minutes (600 seconds) you will need to set its range as follows:

```
custom_plot_->xAxis->setRange(key + some_delta, 600, Qt::AlignRight);
```

Where the value of `some_delta` is up to you. Take a look at the [QCPAxis Class Reference](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPAxis.html#acf60e5b2d631fbc8c4548c3d579cb6d0).